# Why a balloon ToolTip with TTS_CLOSE style cannot be displayed again after the "X" button being clicked? Is this a correct behaviour?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, tooltip

I'm creating a Balloon ToolTip (**TTS_BALLOON**) with an additional style that makes an "X" appear in the upper right corner of this balloon in order to close it (**TTS_CLOSE**).

The type of ToolTip I'm creating is "tracking", ie I show the ToolTip on demand, via the **TTM_TRACKACTIVATE** message, as it is properly explained on MSDN. The ToolTip works correctly, being displayed/hidden upon sending the message **TTM_TRACKACTIVATE**, however, after displaying the ToolTip and clicking the "X", it is correctly hidden, but it is no longer possible to display the ToolTip again in any way, not even using **TTM_TRACKACTIVATE** , nor using **TTM_POPUP**. A similar question was asked on the Visual Studio Forum (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8ff12b85-c0a5-4a69-87d5-0a13ea9c43b0/help-with-ttsclose-style) and not even there the author got an answer to this day.

Speaking of **TTM_POPUP** and its counterpart, **TTM_POP**, after sending a **TTM_POP** message, to "remove the ToolTip from the screen", I could no longer display it, either with **TTM_POPUP** or with **TTM_TRACKACTIVATE**, that is, **TTM_POP** has the same effect as click on the "X", which, in my understanding, only serves to break the ToolTip and make it unusable.

I'm developing a class in Pascal (Delphi) to facilitate the creation and manipulation of ToolTips and now I'm dealing with **TTS_CLOSE** and I don't understand why this happens. It's normal? Is it a Windows API bug?

Below is an example code. To reproduce the problem, create a project of type **Windows VCL Application**, whose only TForm is called **Form1** and put a TButton named **BUTNHint** in this TForm. Then paste the code below completely into the TForm's Unit and then double click on the button that was added and on the TForm's OnShow and OnCreate events to connect the handlers.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    BUTNHint: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure BUTNHintClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FToolTipWindowHandle: HWND;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.BUTNHintClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ToolInfo: TToolInfo;
begin
  if not (SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_GETCURRENTTOOL,0,0) > 0) then
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@ToolInfo,SizeOf(TToolInfo));
    ToolInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TToolInfo);

    SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_TRACKACTIVATE,WPARAM(True),LPARAM(@ToolInfo));
  end
  else
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@ToolInfo,SizeOf(TToolInfo));
    ToolInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TToolInfo);

    SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_TRACKACTIVATE,WPARAM(False),LPARAM(@ToolInfo));
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FToolTipWindowHandle := CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE or WS_EX_TOPMOST
                                        ,TOOLTIPS_CLASS
                                        ,nil
                                        ,TTS_NOPREFIX or TTS_ALWAYSTIP or TTS_BALLOON or TTS_CLOSE
                                        ,0,0,0,0
                                        ,TApplication(Owner).Handle
                                        ,0
                                        ,HInstance
                                        ,nil);

  SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_SETMAXTIPWIDTH,0,500);
  SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_SETTITLE,TTI_INFO,LPARAM(PChar('Título do ToolTip neste SSCCE')));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  ToolInfo: TToolInfo;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@ToolInfo,SizeOf(TToolInfo));

  ToolInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TToolInfo);
  ToolInfo.uFlags := TTF_TRACK or TTF_PARSELINKS;
  ToolInfo.lpszText := 'Lorem ipsum dolor <a id="zzz">sit</a> amet, consectetur adipiscing '+'elit. Nunc eu vulputate ipsum, in dignissim velit. Donec vitae massa rhoncus, tincidunt enim sit amet, venenatis augue. Fusce fringilla pellentesque ligula, ac facilisis enim feugiat a. Nam lacinia eu sed.';

  SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_ADDTOOL,0,LPARAM(@ToolInfo));
end;

end.
```

When running the program press the button to display the ToolTip and click it again to hide the ToolTip. Note that this can be done over and over again, however, if you close the ToolTip by clicking its close button (**X**), the ToolTip will no longer appear, even by clicking the existing button on the TForm several times.

Comment: "*I won't publish any code, since the reproduction of this problem is very simple*" - that is not how this site works. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem in action.

Comment: I have reproduced it. It's hard to say this is a correct behaviour.

Comment: I'll make the SSCCE...

Comment: As I'm not sure if you guys will be notified of my change, I'm writing here that I've already added the sample code. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how it's supposed to work but if you provide a handle to TOOLINFO,, then the window identified by that handle will be notified with a TTN_POP - when you close the tooltip. Handling the WM_NOTİFY you can deactivate the tooltip.  And so you can activate it again.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, The problem is that when hiding the ToolTip using the "X" it can no longer be displayed, either by TTM_TRACKACTIVATE or by TTM_POPUP. I think I didn't quite understand your point, as I can't see a relationship between handling the TTN_POP message and from there showing the ToolTip again. You used the words "disable" and "enable", and just to be clear, there is a way to enable or disable a ToolTip, but I'm talking about hiding and showing the ToolTip, I'm not disabling it, I'm hiding it

Comment: Well, I believe that someone running the example provided will be able to see that something is wrong. I don't know if there's something wrong with my code as it seems very simple to me. Still awaiting...

Comment: After consulting, It should be a correct behavior. The "X" button means closing.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT It makes no sense. If the "close" button meant closing the way you think, the ToolTip window should be automatically destroyed and that's not what happens. Also, the message the ToolTip window receives when the "X" is clicked is WM_SHOWWINDOW with WPARAM = False (0), which, according to the documentation, means the window has been hidden. The close button is just a more intuitive way for the user to HIDE a tracking-type ToolTip, however, after hiding this ToolTip using the "X" it can no longer be displayed normally (TTM_TRACKACTIVATE)

Comment: Considering that the same ToolTip window serves to display several texts and different ToolTips behaviors registered via TTM_ADDTOOL, it also makes no sense that when clicking on the "X" of one of these "views" no other display can be displayed and that's what happens . In other words, clicking the "X" completely breaks the behavior of the ToolTip (ToolTip window) and makes it unusable unless there is indeed something more that needs to be done and that's why I'm here, to try to get an answer :(

Comment: 1- When the tooltip is closed (either by deactivating or pressing the X) a TTN_POP notification is sent if you provide a window handle in TOOLINFO when you add the tool and activate the tip. 2- You can deactivate the tooltip if you handle this notification. 3- Because your problem is, closing does not deactivate the tooltip. 4- You cannot activate a non-deactivated tooltip because it's already active.

Comment: ... as it appears.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You are right and you can achieve the same effect by sending a TTM_TRACKACTIVATE message to hide the ToolTip immediately before running TTM_TRACKACTIVATE to display it. That way I leave optional the use of a handle in TOOLINFO.hwnd, as well as the need to handle the WM_NOTIFY message in the window identified by it. Well now that I know how to fix this I have some questions that I will ask in the comment below

Comment: First, how did you discover the ToolTip's internal behavior when pressing the "X"? According to your explanation, I understand that when hiding a ToolTip there seems to be some kind of internal "flag" which, if active, causes the handling of the TTM_TRACKACTIVATE message to display the ToolTip and that when clicking on the "X ", it appears that this flag is not updated and all attempts to handle the TTM_TRACKACTIVATE message to display the ToolTip fail.

Comment: Second, is this a feature or a bug of the ToolTips implementation on Windows? I believe it's a bug as I haven't seen this explained anywhere and I believe this should be explained clearly along with the TTS_CLOSE style explanation.

Comment: Last but not least, how do you want me to end this question here on SO? If I answer, the points will come to me, but you were the one who answered successfully. Do you intend to reply so that I accept your reply in an official way?

Comment: What I wrote was my guess depending on the observation you provided, I don't have definitive information. I don't think this is a bug but you're right that documentation should mention the difference of hiding and deactivating.

Comment: Best course of closing the question IMO is that you post an answer, as your solution is better - no need for message handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [Sertac Akyuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243614/sertac-akyuz)'s discovery of what actually happens when clicking the "X" button on a ToolTip balloon with the **TTS_CLOSE** style set, I was able to solve the problem by simply forcing the ToolTip to be hidden before actually showing it:

```
procedure TForm1.BUTNHintClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ToolInfo: TToolInfo;
begin
  if not (SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_GETCURRENTTOOL,0,0) > 0) then
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@ToolInfo,SizeOf(TToolInfo));
    ToolInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TToolInfo);
    // Hide the ToolTip window to somehow "synchronize" the internal state of it with the
    // real visibility state, so, the message to show will be successful
    SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_TRACKACTIVATE,WPARAM(False),LPARAM(@ToolInfo));
    SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_TRACKACTIVATE,WPARAM(True),LPARAM(@ToolInfo));
  end
  else
  begin
    ZeroMemory(@ToolInfo,SizeOf(TToolInfo));
    ToolInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TToolInfo);

    SendMessage(FToolTipWindowHandle,TTM_TRACKACTIVATE,WPARAM(False),LPARAM(@ToolInfo));
  end;
end;
```

According to what [Sertac Akyuz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243614/sertac-akyuz) discovered, I came to the conclusion that, when closing the balloon using the "X", the TooTip window is hidden, but some internal control of it, referring to the handling of the TTM_TRACKACTIVATE message is not updated, which makes so that, internally, the ToolTip window "thinks" it is already visible and simply ignores the TTM_TRACKACTIVATE message that should display it. Hiding the ToolTip window before showing it causes a kind of synchronization between what is actually happening and what the window "thinks" is happening.

For me this is a bug, because there is no mention of what happens when the "X" button is clicked in the official documentation and if there is no documentation saying that this is the functionality and, mainly, because it works that way then it is of indeed a bug, in my opinion.